# Calculating averages

Tags: python, list, average

I've struggled with calculating average for values in 2 different lists. Here is what I have been doing (as newbie in python):

```
Averagelist = []
Listofvalues1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
Listofvalues2 = ['5', '6', '7', '8']

for i, x in enumerate(Listofvalues1):
    for j, y in enumerate(Listofvalues2):
        if j == i:
            AVGvalue = (int(x)+int(y)/2)
            Averagelist.append(AVGvalue)
```

I've come up with this way by myself. It might be useless, but so far I can print both values that I want to use for calculation but I get an error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'somevalue'". Could it be the `''` sign?

Cheers!

Comment: Show the contents of `Listofvalues1` and `Listofvalues2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the actual average without having it rounded down, use float. Also you needed an extra pair of brackets otherwise it would be y/2 rather than (x+y/2).

As for that error, I'm not sure what you're using in your Listofvalues lists as input, the the following worked fine for me.

```
Averagelist = []
Listofvalues1 = [1,2]
Listofvalues2 = [6,7]

for i, x in enumerate(Listofvalues1):
    for j, y in enumerate(Listofvalues2):
        if j == i:
            AVGvalue = ((float(x)+float(y))/2)
            Averagelist.append(AVGvalue)

print Averagelist
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked just fine for me as well. I figured out the lack of a pair of brackets just after posting here. Why float works but not int?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need your data to be stored as strings? You will have to covert them to numbers (floats) at one time. This can be done without a for loop, using list comprehension:

```
Listofvalues1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
Listofvalues2 = ['5', '6', '7', '8']
Averagelist = [(float(v1)+float(v2))/2 for (v1, v2) in zip(Listofvalues1, Listofvalues2)]
```

Comment: The code is more complex that I've posted. I am actually grepping values from 2 files and storing in a list. That is why they are already a string. But thanks for you insight!

Comment: @user3223818 I see. So you are doing other stuff in the inner for loop? Otherwise you could try ``for (x, y) in zip(Listofvalues1, Listofvalues2):
    AVGvalue = ((float(x)+float(y))/2)
    Averagelist.append(AVGvalue)``

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean (int(x)+int(y))/2 instead of (int(x)+int(y)/2)?

Comment: How would that make a difference?

Comment: @user3223818 really? Try `2 + 2 / 4` and `(2 + 2) / 4` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
averages = [(float(e[0]) + float(e[1]))/2 for e in zip(Listofvalues1, Listofvalues2)]
```